# A Hölder continuous function whose Fourier coefficients do not decay very fast

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, holder-spaces

At Stein's book of Fourier analysis (Chapter 3, page 91, exercise 15) I was trying to solve the following problem I have to prove that the result

$$\widehat{f}(n)=O\left(\frac{1}{|n|^{\alpha}}\right)$$

Cannot be improved by showing that the function:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^ {−kα} e^{i2^{k}x}$$

with $0<α<1$, satisfies

$$|f (x + h) − f (x)| ≤ C|h|^{α}$$

and $\widehat{f}(N ) = 1/N^{α}$ whenever $N = 2^k$

But I don't know what I am supposed to do here?, there is a hint but it doesn't clarify the question, Can someone help me with this question please?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the Holder continuity exponent in the theorem? If so, then you must check is that the function is $\alpha$ Holder continuous. Then you're done, since the given bound on the Fourier coefficients is easily seen to be tight for this function.

Comment: Yes, in the result I have mentioned  the $\alpha$ is the one of the Holder condition  :) but Holder continous is...?

Comment: So you need to show that $\left | \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k \alpha} \left ( e^{i 2^k x} - e^{i 2^k y} \right ) \right | \leq C |x-y|^\alpha$. To do this I think you will need to perform some balancing of terms: when $k$ is small, the difference in the exponentials is small and the Fourier coefficient is bounded, while when $k$ is large, the reverse occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), is this answer right? https://zr9558.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/fourier-analysis-stein-shararchi-solutions.pdf page 32

Comment: That's a rigorous argument of the type that I was describing. It looks correct. By the way, this is closely related to an interesting topic I studied last semester called the Littlewood-Paley decomposition. I don't know whether this is covered in Stein's book, but it is a nice technique.

Comment: Wow I think in a very close future Im going to start with that hopefully :), so that is the idea you were decribing right?

Comment: The one in the webpage :)

Comment: Yes, that's the idea I had in mind (although I didn't work out how exactly to do the splitting).

Comment: Well so we are done , and I hope in a future point we can discuss the new topic Littlewood-Paley decomposition

Answer (score 5):

This is a Weierstrass-type function. One can prove the continuity by splitting the sum into low frequencies and high frequencies; the cutoff will depend on the scale $h$. Namely, $k_0 = -\log_2 h$.

**High frequencies**. If $k\ge k_0$, then $2^{-k}\le h$, the terms are small enough so that we can simply bound them by the triangle inequality: they contribute $O(h^\alpha)$.

**Low frequencies**. If $k<k_0$, then  the derivative of the $k$th term, namely $i 2^ {k(1-\alpha)} e^{i2^{k}x}$, is bounded by $2^ {k(1-\alpha)} $. Summing this over $k\le k_0$ shows the derivative of the sum of all low-frequency terms is $O(2^{k_0(1-\alpha)})$ which is $O(h^{\alpha-1})$. Hence, the difference of values of this sum on the scale of $h$ is $O(h^\alpha)$.

Comment: (It is complicated to see who the human being might be behind this user-identity... I would be interested to know who understood this question, etc. if you would care to divulge...)

Comment: Well I think this is interesting but how this improves my question ? Well I think is a higher level for me :) can someone clarify?